# How to take outer product of more than two matrices in one shot, in matlab?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, matrix, product

I want to compute `y = a⊗a⊗a`, where `a` is a n-by-1 vector, and `⊗` is the [outer product operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product). In this case `y` should be an n-by-n-by-n tensor.

If `y = a⊗a`, it is easy. I simply do:

```
y = a * a'
```

But what to do in the first case? How do I compute this outer product efficiently in MATLAB if there are more than two vectors?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to compute. Is it `y = a x a x a`? If so, how is the outer product defined when one of the operands is a matrix?

Comment: Yes, I want to compute y = a x a x a. Or higher order ones like, y = a x a x a x a x a.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a multi-dimensional (tensor) case of `y = u⊗v`, I believe that you need to shift the dimensions of the second operand like so:

```
v_t = permute(v, circshift(1:(ndims(u) + ndims(v)), [0, ndims(u)]));
```

and then multiply them with `bsxfun`:

```
y = bsxfun(@times, u, v_t);
```

The regular matrix multiplication is defined only for vector and 2-D matrices, so we couldn't use it in the general case.

Also note that this computation still fails if the second operand is a 1-D vector, because `ndims` returns 2 instead of 1 for vectors. For this purpose, lets define our own function that counts dimensions:

```
my_ndims = @(x)(isvector(x) + ~isvector(x) * ndims(x));
```

To complete the answer, you can define a new function (*e.g*. an anonymous function), like so:

```
outprod = @(u, v)bsxfun(@times, u, permute(v, circshift(1:(my_ndims(u) + my_ndims(v)), [0, my_ndims(u)])));
```

and then use it as many times as you want. For example, `y = a×a×a` would be computed like so:

```
y = outprod(outprod(a, a), a);
```

Of course, you can write a better function that takes a variable number of arguments to save you some typing. Something along these lines:

```
function y = outprod(u, varargin)
    my_ndims = @(x)(isvector(x) + ~isvector(x) * ndims(x));
    y = u;
    for k = 1:numel(varargin)
        v = varargin{k};
        v_t = permute(v, circshift(1:(my_ndims(y) + my_ndims(v)),[0, my_ndims(y)]));
        y = bsxfun(@times, y, v_t);
    end
```

I hope I got the math right!

Answer (score 3):

You can use as well the `kron` function:

```
kron(a * a', a)
```

or when four outer (kronecker tensor) products needed:

```
kron(kron(a * a', a), a)
```

and so on. The last one gives you a **m x n** matrix, where m = n * n * n.

If adding dimensions is desired as going on with the products, you may use the `reshape` function:

```
reshape(kron(a * a', a), [n, n, n])
```

or

```
reshape(kron(kron(a * a', a), a), [n, n, n, n])
```

and so on. The last one gives you a **n x n x n x n** tensor.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using `kron` as in [a previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34875144/8320580) is that it throws off canonical indexing of the outerproduct.

Instead, `ndgrid` is ideal for this scenario:

```
a = [1; 2; 3];
b = [4; 5];
c = [6; 7; 8; 9];

[xx, yy, zz] = ndgrid(1:length(a), 1:length(b), 1:length(c));

% desired outerproduct
M = a(xx) .* b(yy) .* c(zz);
```

On paper, we can check that the desired solution `M` is the datacube:

```
M(:,:,1) = | M(:,:,2) = | M(:,:,3) = | M(:,:,4) = 
           |            |            |
24    30   | 28    35   | 32    40   | 36    45
48    60   | 56    70   | 64    80   | 72    90
72    90   | 84   105   | 96   120   | 108   135
```

Using the Kronecker product approach

```
M2 = reshape(kron(a * b', c), [length(a), length(b), length(c)]);
```

we would get:

```
M2(:,:,1) = | M2(:,:,2) = | M2(:,:,3) = | M2(:,:,4) = 
            |             |             |
24    36    | 64    84    | 30    45    | 80   105
28    48    | 72    96    | 35    60    | 90   120
32    56    | 72   108    | 40    70    | 90   135
```

Datacube `M2` has the same elements as `M`, but these elements are **rearranged**. This is because `kron(a * b', c)` does not contain the slices of `M` in contiguous blocks to facilitate direct application of the  `reshape` function. To compute outerproduct this way, we would need to apply a rearrangement operation/function (determinable, but labrious and time consuming) to the elements of `kron(a * b', c)`.

A further advantage of using `ndgrid` is that it generalizes easily to higher orders.