# kronecker product for an array of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

Is there a way to vectorize the computation of kronecker products for an array of matrices in Matlab? For example, given two 3D array A and B, is it possible to get

```
C(:,:,i) = kron(A(:,:,i),B(:,:,i))
```

without looping over i? So far, I've managed to get the "outer" product of kroneckers working, i.e. C(:,:,i,j) = kron(A(:,:,i),B(:,:,j)) with:

```
matkron_ = @(A,B) reshape(permute(reshape(A(:)*B(:).',[size(A),size(B)]),[4,1,5,2,6,3]),size(A).*size(B))
```

but that does a lot of unnecessary computations when only the "inner" product is needed. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if these solve your problem exactly, but perhaps you could check solutions already given to problems like this on SO? Here's [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14356614/5209610) and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32292179/5209610).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, those are similar but different questions.

Comment: I think that for loop is fine here. All those function handles, and other function calls are very inefficient compared to direct calculation in for loop.

Comment: This great answer works for your problem if `A` and `B` have the same dimensions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28547810/3382783

Comment: WIth Luis's  answer, edit reshape step to : `reshape(z,size(A,1)*size(B,1),[],size(A,3)`.